# how to query course per year level MySql with no relationship

Tags: mysql

how to query course per year level mysql without no relationship?

table 1

```
id course

1  DBA

2  BSCS
```

table 2

```
id  level

1   first year

2   second year

3   third year

4   fourth year
```

see below image expected output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfcrJ.jpg)

Comment: What is your table's name I'm seeing only columns and rows

Comment: What is the result you are expecting to get?

Comment: good day sir i edit the question for more detailed

Comment: You cant get value without relationship.

Comment: @KannanK there is no other way to query this?

Comment: You want to use the idcourse as foreign key in table2.

Comment: @KannanK i want to combine this to table in one query without relationship for example every 1 course have 4 levels

Comment: how you able to join any table without any relationship..or any common column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `cross join`

```
select t1.course, t2.level from table_1 t1 cross join table_2 t2
```